# Showing only most recent record grouped by substrings of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to only show the most recent record based on the criteria of substrings from two columns.

```
SELECT convert(varchar, DateTime, 100) AS "Date and Time"
    ,Text2 AS Area
    ,Substring(Text1, 1,Charindex('/', Text1)-1) AS Device
    ,(Substring(Text1, Charindex('/', Text1)+1, LEN(Text1)) + Substring(PText6, Charindex(' ', PText6)+1, LEN(PText6))) AS Interlock
    ,Substring(PText7, 1,Charindex(':', PText7)-1) AS Username
FROM a_databse.dbo.a_view AS data
WHERE PText6 LIKE '%BypIn%' AND DateTime = (SELECT MAX(DateTime) FROM 
a_database.dbo.a_view WHERE Text1 = data.Text1 AND Interlock = data.Interlock AND PText6 LIKE 'Set%')
```

In the last line

```
Interlock = data.Interlock
```

Needs to be replaced to allow the proper grouping, since the column name "Interlock" isn't valid. However it will only accept true column references such as:

```
Text1 = data.Text1
```

but using substrings:

```
Substring(PText6, Charindex(' ', PText6)+1, LEN(PText6)) = data.Substring(PText6, Charindex(' ', PText6)+1, LEN(PText6))
```

will throw errors:

```
Cannot find either column "data" or the user-defined function or aggregate "data.Substring", or the name is ambiguous
```

Comment: How does using the string expressions cause syntax errors?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added the errors to the question, please see updated version, cheers

Comment: Do you have '/' present in all the records ? if not you may have negative value and may be cause of error

Comment: @Avi The character is present in all records for that specific substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy-paste all expressions properly e.g. `data.SUBSTRING(PText6, ...)` should be `SUBSTRING(data.PText6, ...)`. But you can simplify your query using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DateTime, 100) AS "Date and Time"
     , Text2 AS Area
     , data_vars.Device
     , data_vars.Interlock
     , data_vars.Username
FROM a_databse.dbo.a_view AS data
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Text1, 1, CHARINDEX('/', Text1) - 1) AS Device
         , SUBSTRING(Text1, CHARINDEX('/', Text1) + 1, LEN(Text1)) + SUBSTRING(PText6, CHARINDEX(' ', PText6) + 1, LEN(PText6)) AS Interlock
         , SUBSTRING(PText7, 1, CHARINDEX(':', PText7) - 1) AS Username
) AS data_vars
-- all columns inside data_vars are now accessible inside WHERE, GROUP BY, SELECT and ORDER BY
WHERE PText6 LIKE '%BypIn%' AND DateTime = (
    SELECT MAX(DateTime)
    FROM a_database.dbo.a_view
    WHERE Text1 = data.Text1 AND Interlock = data_vars.Interlock AND PText6 LIKE 'Set%'
)
```